# How to send a video blob to a node.js server by converting it to binary packets?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets

I am using html5 getUserMedia to attain the user's webcam stream and is stored into an object namely stream now i want to send it to the server using socket.io. When I use follwing code i get an array

```
    navigator.getUserMedia  = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
var video=document.querySelector("#outputview");
if( navigator.getUserMedia ) 
{
    navigator.getUserMedia( {video: true, audio: true},successcallback,errorcallback);
    function successcallback( stream ) 
    {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        var socket = io('http://192.168.1.102:8000');
        socket.emit('data',stream);`
```

How to convert this into a data stream so that i could send this stream to view in another page?

Comment: I'd love to know as well.

Answer (score 1):

you may get some help from this demo https://github.com/LingyuCoder/SkyRTC-demo

Comment: I tried that but I can't convert the blob into binary packets.

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? If so, could you please provide that?